# about CTE and physically deleting records from table

Tags: sql

For deleting duplicate records I have found below query on stack overflow which works fine.In this query we are deleting records from "a" and not from  `tblEmployee`.So my question is how duplicate records get physically deleted from physical table though we don't have any `unique` or `primary` key.

```
WITH a as (
    SELECT Firstname,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by Firstname, empID ORDER BY Firstname) 
    AS duplicateRecCount
    FROM dbo.tblEmployee
   )
    --Now Delete Duplicate Records
DELETE
FROM a
WHERE duplicateRecCount > 1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Inorder to understand this, let's consider one of the differences between temp tables and CTE.

When we use Temporary tables, this temp table will be saved in a Tempdb database. So, it is just a copy of your table `tblEmployee`. No matter what changes you make to temp table, it won't affect `tblEmployee`.

But, when you use cte, it is actually pointing to the same table itself. That is why, if you delete from cte, it will affect `tblEmployee` also.
CTE is nothing but a disposable view.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using an updatable CTE in SQL Server.  In this case, the CTE acts the same as a view.

The view is updatable because it refers to only one table and does not have aggregation.  Hence, the effect of the CTE is merely to add columns to the table, tables which can be referenced in the `DELETE` statement.

The conditions for an updatable view are explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).  These conditions are the same as for your CTE.